# Uploading .pdf and .doc files from list of URLs directly to Google Drive

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Sheet with a list of URLs for files - roughly 900 entries, maybe 95% PDFs with a few .docs and .docxs in there as well.

I would like to upload every file to a Google Drive folder - ideally a shared folder within my employer's workspace - retaining the filename, which I also have in the sheet.

I have found some near-answers on here, but they use deprecated Google Scripts methods.

For example:

```
var urlOfThePdf = 'http://www.fostexinternational.com/docs/tech_support/pdfs/280_owners_manual.pdf';// an example of online pdf file
var folderName = 'GAS';// an example of folder name

function saveInDriveFolder(){
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);// get the folde
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlOfThePdf); // get the file content as blob 
  folder.createFile(file);//create the file directly in the folder
}
```

fails at getFileFromURL.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will save the the pdf into the desired folder:

```js
var urlOfThePdf = '';// an example of online pdf file
var folderName = '';// an example of folder name

function saveInDriveFolder(){
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlOfThePdf);

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.createFile(file);
  }
}
```

It uses the [`DriveApp.getFoldersByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename) method to fetch all folders with that name, [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) to fetch the pdf and [`folder.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob) to save the pdf in the folder.

Note that [`DriveApp.getFoldersByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename) fetches a folder iterator (all the folders in your Drive with that name). In this code, I am iterating through **all the folders with that name and saving the pdf in all of them**.

I would recommend using [`Drive.getFolderById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) and supplying the id of your desired folder (can be extracted from the url). Using this, you will only save the pdf in one folder and you will not have to iterate though the folders in the code (the whole while loop can be replace by: `folder.createFile(file);`).

Comment: Not sure if it's need the loop `while`. It could be just `DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next().createFile(file)`